# Can't update app that sigend by google with apk file

Tags: android, apk, sign, android-app-signing

I want a solution to update my app that has been published in google play with direct apk file. But because of difference in my signed apk with google sigend apk it shows error.
Is there any way to let user update app with apk file?

Comment: Sadly, no! Unless you use the same keys for signing the APK, the OS will refuse the updates. From Google Play Console (under Release -> Setup -> App Integrity -> App Signing -> App signing key certificate): _The app signing key itself is not accessible, and is kept on a secure Google server._

Comment: They can delete and reinstall.   Or it can work if you arent using Google Play Signing.  But if you are, you're out of luck-  there's no way to get the signing key and you'd need it